# How can I run a application in Automator?

Tags: macos, applications, automator, script

I want to run an application in Automator but there is no run program.

Operating system and stuff:
OS X Lion 10.7.5
Automator 2.2.4
Memory: 3GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Launch Application** action:

[image]